# AWS Amplify Console GitLab Subgroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create an app with the new [AWS Amplify Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/welcome.html).
As repository service I'm using GitLab.

If my repository is in a [Gitlab subgroup](https://gitlab.com/help/user/group/subgroups/index) the app creation failed with status:

> **Create app failed**
>   The repository url is not valid.

I tried any other combination with public groups, private groups, protected or not. As long as you do not use a subgroup in GitLab everything worked fine.

I want to use subgroups in GitLab to structure many client projects.
Is this a known issue or does anyone know how to use GitLab subgroup with AWS Amplify Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who've ended up here, the Amplify Console supports GitLab subgroups.

Comment: Your right. They fix issues really fast. I forgot to update my question. Thanks for your comment.